# Accept user input perl

Tags: perl, subroutine

How do I accept a list of integers as input? The only thing I can think of is getting each integer from the list specifically using STDIN. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You will have to explain what your problem is with reading from a file handle, as there is no other way to get data into a program and it is hard to guess what might be a *better way*.

Comment: There are many ways of accepting inputs. Which one do *you* want to use?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it:

```
$input = 0;
while($input != -1)
{
    print "add input, finish with -1", "\n";
    $input = <STDIN>;
    chomp($input);
    push(@array, $input);
}
#You also need to remove the last input, -1, with pop:
pop(@array); 
print @array;
```

Console output:

```
add input, finish with -1
1
add input, finish with -1
2
add input, finish with -1
-1
12
```

If the user inputs a tab delimited string of numbers directly,
you can use the splice function to separate the strings.

```
@array = splice(/\t/,$array[0])
```

Comment: When you show code or output, indent the lines by four spaces, so it shows up as a program. You can see how I did this by clicking on `edit` above.

Comment: You never verified your input which can be an issue if you enter in non-integers. You also never `chomp`ed your input which is why each one is on a separate line. You have a hidden _new line_ on the end of each number.

Comment: Thank you David. Also the -1 Has to be removed with pop as well.

Ill edit!

Answer (score 0):

You want input a **list** of integers? I take it you mean that you want to enter a list of numbers, and accept that input if they're all integers.

In this program, I loop forever until I get a valid list, thus `for (;;)`. Some people prefer `while (1)`.

I use [Scalar::Util](http://perldoc.perl.org/Scalar/Util.html)'s `looks_like_number` to test whether the input is numeric, and then use `int` to verify that the number is an integer. You could use a regular expression like `/^\d+$/`, but there's no guarantee that it works in all circumstances. Using `int` and `looks_like_number` guarantees the results.

I assume that a list of integers could be space separated or comma separated or both, thus my `split /[\s,]+/`.

You said:

> The only thing I can think of is getting each integer from the list specifically using STDIN. Is there a better way to do this?

You read in data from a file handle, whether a file or something like `STDIN`. No way around that. However, you can at least make it a single input rather one at a time which I assume you mean.

By the way, I could have combined my numeric test with:

```
if( not looks_like_number $integer or $integer != $integer ) {
```

Since this is an `or` statement, if this would first check if `$input` looks numeric, and if it isn't, would warn about the input before checking to see if it's an integer. However, I'm not sure this is actually clearer than making it too separate statements.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
#
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

use Scalar::Util qw(looks_like_number);

my @integers;           # Storage for my integers
#
# Keep looping until you have a valid input
#
INPUT:
for (;;) {
    print "List of integers: ";
    my $input = <STDIN>;
    chomp $input;
    @integers = split /[\s,]+/, $input;
    #
    # Verify inputted "number" is numeric and an integer
    #
    for my $integer ( @integers ) {
        if( not looks_like_number $integer ) {
            warn qq(Invalid number entered: "$integer");
            next INPUT;
        }
        if( $integer != int $integer ) {
            warn qq(Invalid integer entered: "$integer");
            next INPUT;
        }
    }
    #
    # Exit if there's at least one integer in @integers
    #
    last if @integers;
}
say "Integers: " . join ": ", @integers;
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's one approach, taking a comma-separated list of integers:

```
my $input = <STDIN>;
chomp($input);
if ($input !~ m/^(\d+(,\d+)*)?$/) { die('invalid input'); }
my @input = split(/,/, $input );
```

Or you could read one integer per line:

```
my @input;
while (my $input = <STDIN>) {
    chomp($input);
    if ($input !~ m/^\d+$/) { die('invalid input'); }
    push(@input, $input );
} ## end while
```

Comment: If you want one line `if`, use backwards: `die qq(Invalid input) if $input !~ /^\d+$/`.